# How to return newlines in res.json()

Tags: reactjs, json

I am creating a React.js app and have the following code that is supposed to send a list of errors to the client if the validation of a registration fails:

```
return res.status(400).json({success: false, statusCode: 400, message: "The following errors were encountered: " 
  + "\\n" + errors.username 
  + "\\n" + errors.email 
  + "\\n" + errors.password 
  + "\\n" + errors.confirmPassword
});
```

However, this is what I get when logging the response in the browser console on the frontend:

```
message: "The following errors were encountered: \\nPlease enter a username.\\nPlease enter your email.\\nPassword must be at least 8 characters.\\nPlease confirm your password."
statusCode: 400
success: false
```

How do I make the "\n" characters actually have newlines in the response?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you should just be sending the newlines as `\n` not `\\n`.

`\\n` indicates that you want to show the combination of characters themselves, rather than a newline.
Basically the first backslash *escapes* the second backslash so `\\n` becomes `\n`.

Answer (score 0):

I also suspect the answer by Zidaan Hajat is correct, but here's some more info/another solution:

With es6 template strings (which support multiline strings) you can format the code a lot nicer: (the \n are added automatically)

```
return res.status(400).json({success: false, statusCode: 400, message: 
`The following errors were encountered: 
${errors.username} 
${errors.email}
${errors.password}
${errors.confirmPassword}`
});
```

When rendering these newlines in React, however (assuming you want to preserve the newlines), they will disappear because \n does not work in HTML.

```
<ErrorBox>{error.message}</ErrorBox> // will show the message, but without the \n
```

To output it, I'd go with something like

```
<ErrorBox>{error.message.split('\n').map(line=>(<>{line}<br /></>))}</ErrorBox> // will show the message, but without the \n
```

Note that this adds a `<br />` at the end of the last line, which you might not want but should easily be able to fix.